# Comparing numbers to numbers as strings

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I was trying to figure out why my CoffeeScript code was not working:

**HTML:**

```
<a data-id="5">Click me</a>
```

**CoffeeScript:**

```
id = $('a').attr('data-id')
console.log id == 5
```

The problem is the number being returned from `attr('data-id')` is a string and comparing it to an actual number fails the comparison. What should I be doing differently so that I can easily compare numbers.

Comment: Read about [parseInt](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11465.asp). There is also [parseFloat](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11464.asp) for decimals.

Comment: Maybe you have spaces around the numbers: " 5" versus "5 "

Comment: In javascript `==` would work for this case, but coffeescript converts `==` into `===`. This causes the comparison to be type-sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [parseFloat](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11464.asp) or [parseInt](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11465.asp) methods, and also take a look at jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method which tries to convert content of `data-` attribute to appropriate data type

```
id = $('a').data('id')
console.log id == 5
```

Comment: If you find it to be readable enough, you can always do `+x` instead of using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. It's essentially the same as doing `Number(x)`, I believe.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I did some [tests](http://jsperf.com/9-vs-parseint-9): using `+` is quite a bit faster than parseInt/parseFloat.

Comment: Modified the tests a bit and added tests for `Number`. Now I'm actually getting [different results](http://jsperf.com/9-vs-parseint-9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Same way you do in Javascript

```
id = '5'
console.log parseInt(id, 10) == 5 # parseInt() parses a string as an integer
console.log +id == 5              # + prefix is an "interpret as number" shorthand
console.log id == 5.toString()    # Or convert the other number to a string
```

[Run this here, all report `true`](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20%275%27%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20parseInt%28id%2C%2010%29%20%3D%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%2Bid%20%3D%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20id%20%3D%3D%205.toString%28%29)